# How can I overlay two scatter plots using different Elasticsearch data sources in vega-lite?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite, vega

I want to overlay two scatter plots created from different sources of data using elasticsearch index. I am able to use "layer" to use one data source to create two different plots but not two data sources to create two different plots. The error I get is:

> Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'format')

I can't seem to figure out what the format should be.

My code structure looks like this:

```
{
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
        "layer": [
        {
            "data": {
            "url": {
                "index": "A",
                  "body": {
                    "size": 10000,
                    "_source": ["A_a", "A_b"],
                },
                "format": {"property": "hits.hits"}
              },
              "mark": "type": "circle"
              "encoding": {
              .
              .
              .
            }
          }
        },
        {
            "data": {
            "url": {
                "index": "B",
                  "body": {
                    "size": 10000,
                    "_source": ["B_a", "B_b"],
                },
                "format": {"property": "hits.hits"}
              },
              "mark": "type": "circle"
              "encoding": {
              .
              .
              .
            }
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to change

`"format": {"property": "hits.hits"}` 
to
`"format": {"property": "hits.hits._source"}`

but that didn't fix anything either. How else should I change my format to accommodate two data sources?

Answer (score 0):

Check your formatting with this. In the second layer I just reversed the x/y.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {
        "url": "https://api.npoint.io/186ffeef12c2cb4fd764",
        "format": {"property": "hits.hits"}
      },
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "_source.property.b.c",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {"title": "A"}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "_source.property.b.d",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"title": "B"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "url": "https://api.npoint.io/186ffeef12c2cb4fd764",
        "format": {"property": "hits.hits"}
      },
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "_source.property.b.d",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {"title": "A"}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "_source.property.b.c",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"title": "B"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```

Data:

```
{
   "hits":{
      "hits":[
         {
            "_id":"AcwtemoBAxKStAaIEnOV",
            "_type":"data",
            "_index":"my-index",
            "_score":1,
            "_source":{
               "property":{
                  "a":1,
                  "b":{
                     "c":1,
                     "d":5
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_id":"BMwtemoBAxKStAaIEnOV",
            "_type":"data",
            "_index":"my-index",
            "_score":1,
            "_source":{
               "property":{
                  "a":2,
                  "b":{
                     "c":2,
                     "d":4
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ],
      "total":1499,
      "max_score":1
   },
   "took":1,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "failed":0,
      "skipped":0,
      "successful":5
   },
   "timed_out":false
}
```